# Define startActivity?

Tags: android, button, android-intent

Hy! I need to implement startActivity for a class that define a login button. How can I implement what startActivity() does?

Here is my class :

```
public class LoginButton extends ImageButton {

    private Facebook mFb;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private SessionListener mSessionListener = new SessionListener();
    private String[] mPermissions;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public LoginButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void init(final Activity activity, final Facebook fb) {
        init(activity, fb, new String[] {});
    }

    public void init(final Activity activity, final Facebook fb,
                     final String[] permissions) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mFb = fb;
        mPermissions = permissions;
        mHandler = new Handler();

        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        setImageResource(fb.isSessionValid() ?
                         R.drawable.logout_button : 
                         R.drawable.login_button);
        drawableStateChanged();

        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(mSessionListener);
        SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(mSessionListener);
        setOnClickListener(new ButtonOnClickListener());

    }

    private final class ButtonOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (mFb.isSessionValid()) {
                SessionEvents.onLogoutBegin();
                AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFb);
                asyncRunner.logout(getContext(), new LogoutRequestListener());
            } else {
                mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions,
                              new LoginDialogListener());
                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), com.Xperia.MultipleOptions.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        }
    }

    private final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            SessionEvents.onLoginSuccess();
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onCancel() {
            SessionEvents.onLoginError("Action Canceled");
        }
    }

    private class LogoutRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
        public void onComplete(String response, final Object state) {
            // callback should be run in the original thread, 
            // not the background thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    SessionEvents.onLogoutFinish();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class SessionListener implements AuthListener, LogoutListener {

        public void onAuthSucceed() {
            setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);
            SessionStore.save(mFb, getContext());
        }

        public void onAuthFail(String error) {
        }

        public void onLogoutBegin() {           
        }

        public void onLogoutFinish() {
            SessionStore.clear(getContext());
            setImageResource(R.drawable.login_button);
        }
    }  
}
```

and at line `startActivity(i)` I get

```
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type 
 LoginButton.ButtonOnClickListener
```

Any idea?

Comment: yes because it's extending as imagebutton and not as an acitivity....that means this class is not a activity type class or you can say this class is not an activity at all....so you cannot call startactivity

Comment: I know that my class it's not an activity but I need startActivity when the Button is click...should I do this in the class where I use LoginButton? There is no other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need the app context to start the new intent.

```
Yourclass.this.startActivity(something);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mActivity.startActivity(i);
```

I think that's why you defined mActivity in the first place; perhaps you just forgot to use it.